# in Spring actuator: does HealthEndPoint.health() give the same result as calling /health endpoint?

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-2

I have a Spring boot (2.1.10.RELEASE) application and I have activated actuator to monitor the health of the application. My question as in the title already explained: Is calling the method health of the HealthEndPoint will give the same result as calling e.g. http://localhost:8080/health? Or does the latter checks more things that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the status results will be the same but you can customize the details by creating a custom health indicator to perform some specific health check

**Customizing actuator health endpoint**

```
@Override
    public Health health() {
        int errorCode = check(); // perform some specific health check
        if (errorCode != 0) {
            return Health.down().withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build();
        }
        return Health.up().build();
    }
```